# Как настроить роуты на сайте

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

Есть сайт на хостинге и на сайте есть страницы contact.html, about.html и тд
Как сделать так чтобы роуты в url были не https://site/contact.html, а https://site/contact

Comment: Интернет кишит статьями по настройке роутинга для apache/nginx/прочего

Comment: То что вам нужно называется **Человекопонятный URL**

Comment: погуглить `htaccess + RewriteRule`, написатьпростое праивло, если не получится, то уже сюда с конкретикой